# Run Multiple timer simultaneously in datagrid wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, timer, datagrid

I am new to the Window Presentation Foundation (WPF). I have a Data grid showing data very well but I now want to show time in **Time** column dynamic like call time which is changed every second for every row of data.

here is my class

```
 public class UserTab
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AgentName { get; set; }
    public string Extension { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public string RowDetail { get; set; }
    public int ActiveParticipants { get; set; }
    public int HeldParticipants { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
    public string CallStatus { get; set; }
    public string QueueName { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string CallStatusColor { get; set; }
    public bool isRowDetail { get; set; }
    public List<UserTab> GetUsers()
    {
        List<UserTab> users = new List<UserTab>();
        users.Add(new UserTab() { CallStatusColor = "#1BDA6D", Time = "00:40:00", QueueName = "AMQ", isRowDetail = false, CallStatus = "Ready", Duration = 1000, HeldParticipants = 500, ActiveParticipants = 30, Id = 1, AgentName = "John Doe", Extension = "42033", Name = "John Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1971, 7, 23) });
        users.Add(new UserTab() { CallStatusColor = "#d70d0d", Time = "00:05:00", QueueName = "AMQ", isRowDetail = false, CallStatus = "Not Ready - Lunch", Duration = 1000, HeldParticipants = 500, ActiveParticipants = 30, Id = 3, AgentName = "John Doe", Extension = "42034", Name = "Sammy Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1991, 9, 2) });
        users.Add(new UserTab() { CallStatusColor = "#E6A30C", Time = "00:00:30", QueueName = "AMQ", isRowDetail = true, CallStatus = "Talking", Duration = 1000, HeldParticipants = 500, ActiveParticipants = 30, Id = 1, AgentName = "John Doe", Extension = "42035", Name = "John Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1971, 7, 23) });
        users.Add(new UserTab() { CallStatusColor = "#E6A30C", Time = "00:06:00", QueueName = "AMQ", isRowDetail = true, CallStatus = "Talking", Duration = 1000, HeldParticipants = 500, ActiveParticipants = 30, Id = 2, AgentName = "AJohn Doe", Extension = "42036", Name = "Jane Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1974, 1, 17) });
        users.Add(new UserTab() { CallStatusColor = "#E6A30C", Time = "00:05:00", QueueName = "AMQ", isRowDetail = true, CallStatus = "Talking", Duration = 1000, HeldParticipants = 500, ActiveParticipants = 30, Id = 3, AgentName = "BJohn Doe", Extension = "42037", Name = "Sammy Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1991, 9, 2) });
        users.Add(new UserTab() { CallStatusColor = "#E6A30C", Time = "00:00:55", QueueName = "AMQ", isRowDetail = true, CallStatus = "Talking", Duration = 1000, HeldParticipants = 500, ActiveParticipants = 30, Id = 1, AgentName = "CJohn Doe", Extension = "42038", Name = "John Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1971, 7, 23) });
        users.Add(new UserTab() { CallStatusColor = "#E6A30C", Time = "00:00:40", QueueName = "AMQ", isRowDetail = true, CallStatus = "Talking", Duration = 1000, HeldParticipants = 500, ActiveParticipants = 30, Id = 2, AgentName = "DJohn Doe", Extension = "42039", Name = "Jane Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1974, 1, 17) });
        users.Add(new UserTab() { CallStatusColor = "#E6A30C", Time = "00:55:00", QueueName = "AMQ", isRowDetail = true, CallStatus = "Talking", Duration = 1000, HeldParticipants = 500, ActiveParticipants = 30, Id = 3, AgentName = "EJohn Doe", Extension = "42003", Name = "Sammy Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1991, 9, 2) });
        users.Add(new UserTab() { CallStatusColor = "#1BDA6D", Time = "00:06:00", QueueName = "AMQ", isRowDetail = false, CallStatus = "Ready", Duration = 1000, HeldParticipants = 500, ActiveParticipants = 30, Id = 1, AgentName = "EJohn Doe", Extension = "42053", Name = "John Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1971, 7, 23) });
        users.Add(new UserTab() { CallStatusColor = "#1BDA6D", Time = "00:10:00", QueueName = "AMQ", isRowDetail = false, CallStatus = "Ready", Duration = 1000, HeldParticipants = 500, ActiveParticipants = 30, Id = 2, AgentName = "FJohn Doe", Extension = "42073", Name = "Jane Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1974, 1, 17) });
        users.Add(new UserTab() { CallStatusColor = "#1BDA6D", Time = "00:00:20", QueueName = "AMQ", isRowDetail = false, CallStatus = "Ready", Duration = 1000, HeldParticipants = 500, ActiveParticipants = 30, Id = 3, AgentName = "GJohn", Extension = "42078", Name = "Sammy", Birthday = new DateTime(1991, 9, 2) });
        users.Add(new UserTab() { CallStatusColor = "#1BDA6D", Time = "00:00:41", QueueName = "AMQ", isRowDetail = false, CallStatus = "Ready", Duration = 1000, HeldParticipants = 500, ActiveParticipants = 30, Id = 1, AgentName = "HJohn Doe", Extension = "42083", Name = "John Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1971, 7, 23) });
        users.Add(new UserTab() { CallStatusColor = "#1BDA6D", Time = "00:25:00", QueueName = "AMQ", isRowDetail = false, CallStatus = "Ready", Duration = 1000, HeldParticipants = 500, ActiveParticipants = 30, Id = 2, AgentName = "IJohn Doe", Extension = "42093", Name = "Jane Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1974, 1, 17) });
        users.Add(new UserTab() { CallStatusColor = "#1BDA6D", Time = "00:00:00", QueueName = "AMQ", isRowDetail = false, CallStatus = "Ready", Duration = 1000, HeldParticipants = 500, ActiveParticipants = 30, Id = 3, AgentName = "JJohn Doe", Extension = "42013", Name = "Sammy Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1991, 9, 2) });
       
        return users;
    }
}

  public partial class Tabs : Window
  { 
        InitializeComponent();
        List<UserTab> us = new List<UserTab>();
        UserTab user = new UserTab();
        us = user.GetUsers();
        dgSimple.ItemsSource = us
}
```

here is DataGrid

```
 <DataGrid Name="dgSimple" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" CellStyle="{StaticResource Body_Content_DataGrid_Centering}" Height="350" EnableRowVirtualization="False">
                                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Agent Name" Binding="{Binding AgentName}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                                            <DataGridTemplateColumn SortMemberPath="CallStatus" CanUserSort="True" Header="Status" CellTemplate="{StaticResource StatusTemplate}"/>
                                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time" Binding="{Binding Time}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Extension" Binding="{Binding Extension}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                                        </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure if you follow any design patterns since you didn't provide any code but would be silly that each row has its own timer ticking (imagine if you have 10 000 rows = 10 000 timers ticking?). Probably you need one timer that loops thru each row and updates the time of each row  (view model / model if you use mvvm design pattern)

Comment: I am not using any design pattern. can you provide me some code implementation

Comment: How about a multibinding for this column?  One binding to your viewmodel value and another to whatever difference is to drive this.  Change that difference each second. Calculate what you want to show in the cell using a multiconverter.  It does depend on how many rows worth of data you have though.  You could have one timer and iterate all the row viewmodels once a second. Which should be fine if you have hundreds of whatever those rows are. Looks like call centre data to me. That's unlikely to mean thousands of agents.

Answer (score 0):

A simple sample based on your code, it refresh the `DataGrid` every 1 second.

1. In class `Tabs`, start a new thread by `StartMockValue` to mock `Time` value.
2. In `StartRefreshDataGrid`, start a new thread to determine whether to update the `DataGrid`
3. If the `Time` is different from `DisplayTime`, then set `UserTab -> DisplayTime` to notify property changed.
4. Finally, the `DataGrid` updated by new data.

**Tabs.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpfApp.Tabs"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
         <DataGrid Name="dgSimple" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Height="350"
                   EnableRowVirtualization="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Agent Name" Binding="{Binding AgentName}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn SortMemberPath="CallStatus" CanUserSort="True" Header="Status"/>
                <!--NOTE: bind 'DisplayTime' instead of 'Time'-->
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time" Binding="{Binding DisplayTimeString}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Extension" Binding="{Binding Extension}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
         </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Tabs.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace TestWpfApp
{
    public partial class Tabs : Window
    {
        public Tabs()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Users = new List<UserTab>();
            UserTab user = new UserTab();
            this.Users = user.GetUsers();
            dgSimple.ItemsSource = this.Users;

            this.StartMockValue(); 

            this.StartRefreshDataGrid();
        }

        private List<UserTab> Users;

        private void StartMockValue()
        {
            // NOTE: this is a thread to mock the business logic, it change 'Time' value.
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var rando = new Random();
                while (true)
                {
                    foreach (var user in this.Users)
                    {
                        if (rando.Next(0, 3) == 1)
                        {
                            user.Time = user.Time + 1;
                        }
                    }

                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            });
        }

        public void StartRefreshDataGrid()
        {
            // NOTE: this is a thread to update data grid.
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    foreach (var user in this.Users)
                    {
                        // NOTE: update if the time changed.
                        if (user.DisplayTime != user.Time)
                        {
                            user.DisplayTime = user.Time;
                        }
                    }

                    // NOTE: refresh the grid every seconds.
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**UserTab.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TestWpfApp
{
    public class UserTab : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string AgentName { get; set; }
        public string Extension { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
        public string RowDetail { get; set; }
        public int ActiveParticipants { get; set; }
        public int HeldParticipants { get; set; }
        public int Duration { get; set; }
        public string CallStatus { get; set; }
        public string QueueName { get; set; }

        // NOTE: this is the 'real time', some business thread will update the value.
        public int Time { get; set; }

        private int displayTime;

        // NOTE: this is the 'displayed time' in the DataGrid.
        public int DisplayTime
        {
            get => displayTime;
            set
            {
                displayTime = value;
                this.OnPropertyChange(nameof(this.DisplayTimeString));
            }
        }

        public string DisplayTimeString => $"{displayTime / 60 / 60}:{displayTime / 60 % 60}:{displayTime % 60}";

        public string CallStatusColor { get; set; }
        public bool isRowDetail { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChange(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        public List<UserTab> GetUsers()
        {
            var maxSeconds = 24 * 60 * 60;
            var random = new Random();


            List<UserTab> users = new List<UserTab>();
            users.Add(new UserTab() { CallStatusColor = "#1BDA6D", DisplayTime = random.Next(0, maxSeconds), QueueName = "AMQ", isRowDetail = false, CallStatus = "Ready", Duration = 1000, HeldParticipants = 500, ActiveParticipants = 30, Id = 1, AgentName = "John Doe", Extension = "42033", Name = "John Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1971, 7, 23) });
            users.Add(new UserTab() { CallStatusColor = "#d70d0d", DisplayTime = random.Next(0, maxSeconds), QueueName = "AMQ", isRowDetail = false, CallStatus = "Not Ready - Lunch", Duration = 1000, HeldParticipants = 500, ActiveParticipants = 30, Id = 3, AgentName = "John Doe", Extension = "42034", Name = "Sammy Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1991, 9, 2) });
            users.Add(new UserTab() { CallStatusColor = "#E6A30C", DisplayTime = random.Next(0, maxSeconds), QueueName = "AMQ", isRowDetail = true, CallStatus = "Talking", Duration = 1000, HeldParticipants = 500, ActiveParticipants = 30, Id = 1, AgentName = "John Doe", Extension = "42035", Name = "John Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1971, 7, 23) });
            users.Add(new UserTab() { CallStatusColor = "#E6A30C", DisplayTime = random.Next(0, maxSeconds), QueueName = "AMQ", isRowDetail = true, CallStatus = "Talking", Duration = 1000, HeldParticipants = 500, ActiveParticipants = 30, Id = 2, AgentName = "AJohn Doe", Extension = "42036", Name = "Jane Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1974, 1, 17) });
            users.Add(new UserTab() { CallStatusColor = "#E6A30C", DisplayTime = random.Next(0, maxSeconds), QueueName = "AMQ", isRowDetail = true, CallStatus = "Talking", Duration = 1000, HeldParticipants = 500, ActiveParticipants = 30, Id = 3, AgentName = "BJohn Doe", Extension = "42037", Name = "Sammy Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1991, 9, 2) });
            users.Add(new UserTab() { CallStatusColor = "#E6A30C", DisplayTime = random.Next(0, maxSeconds), QueueName = "AMQ", isRowDetail = true, CallStatus = "Talking", Duration = 1000, HeldParticipants = 500, ActiveParticipants = 30, Id = 1, AgentName = "CJohn Doe", Extension = "42038", Name = "John Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1971, 7, 23) });
            users.Add(new UserTab() { CallStatusColor = "#E6A30C", DisplayTime = random.Next(0, maxSeconds), QueueName = "AMQ", isRowDetail = true, CallStatus = "Talking", Duration = 1000, HeldParticipants = 500, ActiveParticipants = 30, Id = 2, AgentName = "DJohn Doe", Extension = "42039", Name = "Jane Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1974, 1, 17) });
            users.Add(new UserTab() { CallStatusColor = "#E6A30C", DisplayTime = random.Next(0, maxSeconds), QueueName = "AMQ", isRowDetail = true, CallStatus = "Talking", Duration = 1000, HeldParticipants = 500, ActiveParticipants = 30, Id = 3, AgentName = "EJohn Doe", Extension = "42003", Name = "Sammy Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1991, 9, 2) });
            users.Add(new UserTab() { CallStatusColor = "#1BDA6D", DisplayTime = random.Next(0, maxSeconds), QueueName = "AMQ", isRowDetail = false, CallStatus = "Ready", Duration = 1000, HeldParticipants = 500, ActiveParticipants = 30, Id = 1, AgentName = "EJohn Doe", Extension = "42053", Name = "John Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1971, 7, 23) });
            users.Add(new UserTab() { CallStatusColor = "#1BDA6D", DisplayTime = random.Next(0, maxSeconds), QueueName = "AMQ", isRowDetail = false, CallStatus = "Ready", Duration = 1000, HeldParticipants = 500, ActiveParticipants = 30, Id = 2, AgentName = "FJohn Doe", Extension = "42073", Name = "Jane Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1974, 1, 17) });
            users.Add(new UserTab() { CallStatusColor = "#1BDA6D", DisplayTime = random.Next(0, maxSeconds), QueueName = "AMQ", isRowDetail = false, CallStatus = "Ready", Duration = 1000, HeldParticipants = 500, ActiveParticipants = 30, Id = 3, AgentName = "GJohn", Extension = "42078", Name = "Sammy", Birthday = new DateTime(1991, 9, 2) });
            users.Add(new UserTab() { CallStatusColor = "#1BDA6D", DisplayTime = random.Next(0, maxSeconds), QueueName = "AMQ", isRowDetail = false, CallStatus = "Ready", Duration = 1000, HeldParticipants = 500, ActiveParticipants = 30, Id = 1, AgentName = "HJohn Doe", Extension = "42083", Name = "John Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1971, 7, 23) });
            users.Add(new UserTab() { CallStatusColor = "#1BDA6D", DisplayTime = random.Next(0, maxSeconds), QueueName = "AMQ", isRowDetail = false, CallStatus = "Ready", Duration = 1000, HeldParticipants = 500, ActiveParticipants = 30, Id = 2, AgentName = "IJohn Doe", Extension = "42093", Name = "Jane Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1974, 1, 17) });
            users.Add(new UserTab() { CallStatusColor = "#1BDA6D", DisplayTime = random.Next(0, maxSeconds), QueueName = "AMQ", isRowDetail = false, CallStatus = "Ready", Duration = 1000, HeldParticipants = 500, ActiveParticipants = 30, Id = 3, AgentName = "JJohn Doe", Extension = "42013", Name = "Sammy Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1991, 9, 2) });
            return users;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. what if I do not want to update the whole grid after every second. I just want to update the specific column like in my case "Time"

Comment: Do you mean you want to update only changed rows? Compare the ```real value``` with the DataGrid ```display value```, if the value changed, then update the field ```Time``` will work~

Comment: I updated the answer, and it refresh only the cells that the value has changed.

Comment: As you can see in reference to Datagrid Image Time Column values. I just want to increment of one second after binding the data to the grid without updating the value in User List.

as a reference https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/onedrive/en-US/38250898-3eeb-44eb-824e-6eb661795bc5/automatically-updating-datagrid-column?forum=wpf

Comment: My suggestion is to write two model, separate business logic with the view, and use ```ViewModel``` to update ```View```. Reference here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel